# Can URLs in CSS Custom Properties be relative to the defining CSS file?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS library that can be hosted and consumed from anywhere (e.g. via CDN) that also contains resources like images or fonts. I want to make URLs to those resources available as Custom CSS Properties. Those URLs have to be relative to the library. E.g.

```html
<!-- https://my.server/index.html -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://my.cdn/a/lib.css">
<div style="background-image: var(--img)"></div>
```

```css
/* https://my.cdn/a/lib.css */
@property --img {
  syntax: "<url>";
  initial-value: none;
  inherits: true;
}

:root {
  --img: url(./img.svg);
}
```

```html
<!-- https://my.cdn/a/img.svg -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- […] -->
</svg>
```

I look for a way to make the effective background-image URL of the `div` https://my.cdn/a/img.svg (without directly referencing that, `--img` could be `none` or point to a entirely different URL sometimes). However, the URL will always be relative to the document (i.e. the URL will be https://my.server/img.svg). Even worse, it is relative to the stylesheet that uses the CSS Custom Property. I.e. if I had

```css
/* https://my.server/b/lib.css */
@import url("https://my.cdn/a/lib.css");
div {
  background-image: var(--img);
}
```

it would effectively be https://my.server/b/img.svg.

As a workaround, `a/lib.css` itself provides CSS classes that apply the CSS Custom Properties, like

```css
/* https://my.cdn/a/lib.css */
/* […] */
.img--background-image {
  background-image: var(--img);
}
```

With that, consumers can apply the class and the URL is resolved correctly, like

```html
<!-- https://my.server/index.html -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://my.cdn/a/lib.css">
<div class="img--background-image"></div>
```

Obviously, this workaround is flawed, as it limits the way `--img` can be used to the use-cases foreseen by the library. And you have to change HTML (by adding the class) to use it.

I think when I tried back when Chrome implemented `@property`, that then the URL was resolved correctly. However, today this is not the case.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? How did you solve it? Am I missing the obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `none` is not a valid initial value for `<url>`.
Chrome's console will report the issue in its "Issues" tab, which is easily missable, and Safari will stay silent, but at least in JS the error is quite clear:

```js
CSS.registerProperty({
  name: "--img",
  syntax: "<url>",
  inherits: true,
  initialValue: "none",
});
// In Chrome and Safari this throws (not the same error o_0)
// with the message "The initial value provided does not parse for the given syntax."
// or similar.
```

So your registration failed and the `url()` is only resolved when the variable is actually being used as an `<url>`, i.e. in your user's stylesheet, and thus it becomes relative to their stylesheet.

If you did register the property correctly, using a valid `url()` `initial-value`, then the URL would be resolved at definition time, and be relative to whatever stylesheet the definition was made in.

So you could for instance have set

```css
@property --img {
  syntax: "<url>";
  initial-value: url();
  inherits: true;
}
```

There is even a complete example demonstrating that behavior in the specs:
https://drafts.css-houdini.org/css-properties-values-api/#example-57a63cfb

Ps: You might be interested in following [this related issue](https://github.com/w3c/css-houdini-drafts/issues/1109).

Comment: Amazing that there's such a simple answer. Thank you!